# Regex to change ASCII table formatting

Tags: python, regex

I have a table like this:

```
head1   | head2 | head3
=======================
foo=bar | baz   | quuux
```

Is there a regular expression, that replaces the line of equal signs with a line of dashes, but leaves the other equal signs in the table alone? The line consisting of dashes must be of equal length as the line consisting of equal signs.

Expected output

```
head1   | head2 | head3
-----------------------
foo=bar | baz   | quuux
```

I'm using the Python re library.

Comment: What's your expected output? Which language are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=(?=={2,}|$)
```

Try this.Replace by `-`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/73

Comment: Fails for `foo | bar | quu==`

Comment: @georg i guess OP should calrify on it.Anyways its a small fix

Comment: `{1,}` is longer, less portable, and less readable than just `+`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a regular expression, that replaces the line of equal signs with a line of dashes

I would do like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''head1   | head2 | head3
=======================
foo=bar | baz   | quuux'''
>>> for i in s.split('\n'):             # Splits the input according to the newline character and iterate through the contents.
        if re.match(r'^=+$', i):        # If the item has only equal signs then 
            print(i.replace('=', '-'))  # replace = with - dashes
        else:
            print(i)                    # else print the whole line


head1   | head2 | head3
-----------------------
foo=bar | baz   | quuux
```

Comment: You don't need the `(?m)` modifier - you're already working with single lines. Otherwise, that's what I would do as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have lines starting with `==` or `foo=bar` you can use a normal str.replace.

```
s="""
head1   | head2 | head3
=======================
foo=bar | baz   | quuux
"""
out  = ""

for line in s.splitlines(True):
    if line.startswith("="): # or if line[0]== "=" 
        out += line.replace("=", "-")
    else:
        out += line
print(out)
head1   | head2 | head3
-----------------------
foo=bar | baz   | quuux
```

This should cover cases where you only have = in the line and be more efficient than a regex:

```
for line in s.splitlines(True):
    if not line.rstrip().translate(None,"="): # or if line[0]== "="
        out += line.replace("=","-")
    else:
        out += line
print(out)
```